# calling two different methods of web service in a single activity

Tags: android, web-services

I have a `web service` which has two different methods like '`returnInt`' and '`returnImg`'.
Is it possible to call these two methods in my single android activity?
I am using `kSOAP` for this and I have a java WebService.

Answer (score 0):

Well in my application;

I have a Python XML WebService on the server side. On the client side I use [Android-xmlrpc](http://code.google.com/p/android-xmlrpc/) library which is a very thin and open source library and works great for my case.

In the client application, it is possible to call more than one method of the WebService within the same activity. But I suggest to, issue webService calls on the separate threads. Also be sure that your web server is multi-threaded and capable of concurrent calls.

Answer (score 0):

yes its possible to call any number of WS from an acitivty. Just make sure that each WS call is running in a different thread and if one WS call needs to precede the other then proper handling using message queues is done.